# Wrong month shows for July when culture is set to ar-AE in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, webforms, uiculture

Website show wrong month for `july`in arabic, this is Arabic website developed in asp.net webform and culture is set properly to '**ar-AE**' and event date shows correct month on local machine but on productions it show month which belongs to `Egyptian culture`

Date in database is stored as `smalldatetime` in this format `2017-07-25 00:00:00`

Wrong month for July

Correct month on local-host :`25 يوليو 2017`

Wrong month on production : `25 يوليه 2017`

```
<asp:Label  ID="lblDate"  runat="server"  Text='<%# FormatDate(Eval("PublishDate")) %>'>
</asp:Label>

protected string FormatDate(object dt) {
  string date = String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", dt);
  date = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", dt);
  // Response.Write(date + "<br/>");
  return date;
}
```

Culture is set to UAE correctly

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() {
  String lang = "ar-AE";
  CultureInfo ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
  // Call function to detect Language and assign  to session variable
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);

  base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

What could be the reason, could it be production server itself?

We check almost all possibilities and tried everything, it just gets wrong month for July rest all is ok.

I also cross check production server Language setting, IIS settings, it all seems to be okay, only thing i can point is that server has all latest updates, may be we are missing something. we tested same on different windows 7 machine it just works fine.

Update: I have tried solution suggest also but it keeps showing wrong month for JULY `يوليه`. This is wrong. We tested it also it show the correct culture on the server.

Fiddle example also show wrong month https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAOJ7H

Comment: The object passed to `FormatDate` is a `DateTime`? _"Date in database is stored in this format"_ A date is never stored in a format in the database. It **should** be stored as a `datetime` or `date` which has no format. If it was stored as a string(varchar) you should fix that first.

Comment: I'd suggest explicitly using the `string.Format` overload that accepts a `CultureInfo` as a `IFormatProvider`, or to set the culture in the `Web.config` file as described here: https://forums.asp.net/t/1318941.aspx?How+to+Set+default+language+in+web+config+file+

Comment: @MartinCostello: Should be unncessary. OP is already using a recommended way which should work

Comment: There could be some thread-related subtlety going on that isn't visible from the code that's presented causing the difference, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, object which i pass to FormaDate is DateTime `2017-07-25 00:00:00`

Comment: Updated question with more details for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find localized `DateTime` month name by using these lines of code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2017-07-25 00:00:00");

string arabicMonth = new CultureInfo("ar-AE").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(dt.Month);
```

The resulted code gives `يوليه` instead of `يوليو`, indicating something went wrong in Windows localization of Gregorian month names in Arabic language.

By finding out a little bit, it caused by `locale.nls` file located in `%WINDIR%\System32\locale.nls` containing incorrect data where *the month of July is displayed in other Arabic version than current system culture using*.

Since NLS file is formatted in binary, it's hard to read and edit stored locale information even viewing it in hex editor. AFAIK, this problem already fixed by Microsoft in **KB981981** update for Windows 7 & Server 2008 R2 systems, you can perform update depending on platform used (requires restart afterwards):

[Update for Windows 7 32-bit (KB981981) - 5/24/2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16270&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True&a03ffa40-ca8b-4f73-0358-c191d75a7468=True)

[Update for Windows 7 64-bit (KB981981) - 5/24/2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11611)

NB: Ensure that all affected machines installed with this update for best result. If you can't install the update due to certain restrictions, I suggest to try using jQuery plugin for `datepicker` which shows `يوليو` for month of July as workaround.

PS: I also tried zahed's solution in the OP's fiddle -

```
DateTime.Parse("2017-07-25 00:00:00").ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"))
```

But it shows `25 الثلاثاء , يوليه, 2017` (i.e. `يوليه`) too, hence it's not the string formatting problem, instead the Windows localization problem as explained above.

References:

[Description of Software Update Services and Windows Server Update Services changes in content for 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2492172/description-of-software-update-services-and-windows-server-update-serv)

[How to convert the month name in english text in datetime to arabic text using C#?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c297381-209b-4077-8061-75229e67b14b/how-to-convert-the-month-name-in-english-text-in-datetime-to-arabic-text-using-c?forum=netfxbcl)

Related:

[Michael S. Kaplan - Arabic locales for month names](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2011/02/09/10125506.161918.html)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the 100 Solution but i am sure it has to do something with OS or updates. Updates you are pointing to are very old & for windows seven while i am facing issue on windows server 2102 R2 version and also on fiddle what about that. Anyways i will mark your anyways as it is better explained but may not to the actual solution .https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAOJ7H

Answer (score 0):

Design code:

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Code behind C#:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Parse("2017-07-25 00:00:00").ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
}
```

**Updated answer:**

I would imagine all languages that the OS supports (considering that is where the information comes from).

Here is a list:  [default supported languages by OS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx).

Comment: Which machine you have tested on OS, version as it works for us also on two local machine with windows 7 but not on windows 2012 R2 version. even fiddles also generates wrong month name https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAOJ7H

Comment: can you tell me the windows version in production server ? I will update you the answer. @Learning

Comment: Please check my updated answer will help to out your issue. @Learning